# How to disable field in field array from component?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I need to disable the field in fieldArray, however I haven't found any APi to do that. I can't pass a variable to the field like `disabled={isDisabled}` because I'm using field array.

```
{fields.map((e, i) => (
  <TableRow
    key={i}
    className={classes.row}
    onClick={() => chooseBill(i)}
    style={{ backgroundColor: currentBill == i && '#cff3ff' }}
  >
    <TableCell className="tb-cell">
      <Field
        name={`${e}.condition_related_to`}
        component="input"
        onChange={onChangeForm}
        type="radio"
        value="employment_in"
      />
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell className="tb-cell">
      <Field
        name={`${e}.condition_related_to`}
        component="input"
        onChange={onChangeForm}
        type="radio"
        value="auto_accident_in"
        onClick={() => window.alert('You must fill `state` for auto accident')}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell className="tb-cell">
        <Field
          name={`${e}.condition_related_to`}
          component="input"
          onChange={changeForm}
          type="radio"
          value="other_accident_in"
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell className="tb-cell" style={{ overflow: 'visible', minWidth: 50 }}>
        <Field
          name={`${e}.accident_place`}
          myStyles={tableSelectStyles}
          onChange={onChangeForm}
          disabled={!isConditionRelatedToDisabled}
          placeholder=""
          component={tableSelect}
          options={[{ label:'NY', value:'NY' }, { label:'NJ', value:'NJ' }, { label:'CT', value:'CT' }, { label:'CT', value:'CT' }]}
        />
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
```

Here I have the field `"accident_place"` which has to be `disabled` if the field `"condition_related_to"` is equal to `"employment_in"`.

Comment: Could you provide some code so we can help you better?

Comment: What do you mean by *can't pass a variable to the field like disabled={isDisabled} because I'm using field array*. Fields are still rendered within FieldsArray. Secondly could you please show your tableSelect component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of an item in the FieldArray using `fields.get(index)` [documentation here](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/#-code-fields-get-index-function-code-)

So the solution is going to look something like this (I just cut out the non-relevant parts).

```
{fields.map((e, i) => (
      ...
        <Field
          name={`${e}.accident_place`}
          disabled={fields.get(i).condition_related_to === 'employment_in'}
          ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Field Component takes in a component prop which you are using too. As I understand from your question you wish to disable the field

```
 <Field
      name={`${e}.accident_place`}
      myStyles={tableSelectStyles}
      onChange={onChangeForm}
      disabled={!isConditionRelatedToDisabled}
      placeholder=""
      component={tableSelect}
      options={[{ label:'NY', value:'NY' }, { label:'NJ', value:'NJ' }, { label:'CT', value:'CT' }, { label:'CT', value:'CT' }]}
    />
```

Now adding a `disabled` prop to `input, textarea or select` field component directly will disable them. However in order to disable the field for a custom component which in your case is `tableSelect`, you need to receive the `disabled` Prop in your component and pass it on to the Select field that you use

```
const tableSelect = ({disabled, options, onChange, onBlur, name, value  ...rest}) => {

    return (
      <select 
         disabled={disabled}
         onChange={onChange}
         name={name}
         value={value}
     >
         {options.map(option => {/* return option here */})}
     </select>
   )

}
```

Using the disabled prop in custom component is important because otherwise the disabled prop will not be honoured. Also make sure that if you are using any library for select, you are passing in the disabled prop by the name the library requires

Comment: Interesting. My reading was more the OP is wondering how to get the `isConditionRelatedToDisabled` condition, since the values of the fieldArray items aren't directly available. But also true that the disabled prop on their custom `tableSelect` component needs to work!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable  which ultimately will disable the  as well.

CSS

```
disabled
{
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #CCC;
}
```

React

```
<TableCell className={`tb-cell ${`${e}.condition_related_to === "employment_in" ? "disabled": ""`}`} style={{ overflow: 'visible', minWidth: 50 }}>
        <Field
          name={`${e}.accident_place`}
          myStyles={tableSelectStyles}
          onChange={onChangeForm}
          placeholder=""
          component={tableSelect}
          options={[{ label:'NY', value:'NY' }, { label:'NJ', value:'NJ' }, { label:'CT', value:'CT' }, { label:'CT', value:'CT' }]}
        />
      </TableCell>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-skdmo?file=/demo.js)

**OR**

You can just disable field with same approach

```
<Field
    name={`${e}.accident_place`}
    myStyles={tableSelectStyles}
    onChange={onChangeForm}
    placeholder=""
    component={tableSelect}
    options={[{ label:'NY', value:'NY' }, { label:'NJ', value:'NJ' }, { 
    label:'CT', value:'CT' }, { label:'CT', value:'CT' }]}
    className={`tb-cell ${`${e}.condition_related_to === "employment_in" ? "disabled": 
    ""`}`}
 />
```